# Conversion to swift from objective-c

Tags: swift, openears

I'm currently trying to convert the objective-c code to swift of the sample app provided by openEars. However there is this one line of code :

```
[[OEPocketsphinxController sharedInstance] setActive:TRUE error:nil];
```

How is this written in swift?

It was defined like this in the framework:

```
+ (OEPocketsphinxController *)sharedInstance;
/**This needs to be called with the value TRUE before setting properties of OEPocketsphinxController for the first time in a session, and again before using OEPocketsphinxController in case it has been called with the value FALSE.*/
- (BOOL)setActive:(BOOL)active error:(NSError **)outError;
```

However I did try something like this:

```
OEPocketsphinxController(TRUE, error: nil)
```

The compiler error was:

> Swift Compiler Error Expected declaration

Comment: OpenEars developer here – just wanted to let you know that OpenEars now has full Swift 3 support and docs including a sample app you can check out in order to see Swift function signatures such as these – sorry it didn't at the time you asked!

Comment: @Halle Thanks. Will look into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Swift code you've called would look like this in Objective-C:

```
[[OEPocketsphinxController alloc] initWith:YES error:nil]
```

Sort of...

You're trying to call a constructor which does not exist.  Instead, we must go through the `sharedInstance`:

```
OEPocketsphinxController.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)
```

`sharedInstance()` is a class method of the `OEPocketsphinxController` class which returns an instance of the `OEPocketsphinxController`.

`setActive(:error:)` is an instance method of the `OEPocketsphinxController` class and must be called on an instance of this class.

So, we want to use `sharedInstance()` to get an instance on which to call the `setActive(:error:)` method on.

The following two pieces of code are exactly equivalent:

#### Swift:

```
OEPocketsphinxController.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)
```

#### Objective-C:

```
[[OEPocketsphinxController sharedInstance] setActive:TRUE error:nil];
```